# Conflict between disk and memory version of code

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Practically each major change I make in Android Studio is reverted.

I've a kind of backup file named `<originalFilemane>_conflict-<datetime>.<ext>` where I can find my changes.

Why Android Studio is doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a bad habit!

I should stop doing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on `IntelliJ` derived editors.